# Why does BOM stick around when reading a UTF-8 file?

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to read some UTF-8 encoded CSV files (at least I believe that's what they are) in Perl, and write them all out into one larger file. Here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $out, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', "output.csv" or die "Cannot open output.csv: $!";

my @files = <*.csv>;
foreach(@files) {
    next if $_ =~ m/^output.csv$/;

    print "Parsing $_\n";

    open my $in, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $_ or die "Cannot open $_: $!";
    while(<$in>) {
        chomp;
        next if m/^\s*$/;
        print $out "$_\n";
    }
    close $in;
}
close $out;
```

When all is said and done, each file's contents starts with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), meaning that a BOM shows up as the first three bytes of each file's data. Shouldn't opening the file using the `>:encoding(UTF-8)` directive have gotten rid of the BOM? Why does it continue to show up in my output?

Comment: No, a BOM is simply the character [U+FEFF](http://www.mclean.net.nz/ucf/?c=U+FEFF) at the start of the file. By convention this is used to signal the byte ordering and is therefore not needed at all on UTF8 files. But it is just a character and does not get discarded unless you write code to discard it.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention a BOM on a UTF8 file is redundant as a byte order mark (UTF8 only has one byte order), but some MS apps consider it significant. If you plan to open the CSV files in Excel for example, you almost certainly want to retain the BOM.

Comment: @GrantMcLean: I hope I'm not being too picky, but *“UTF-8 only has one byte order”* may be misleading. It's akin to remembering how to lay a place setting at a dining table. I must know whether the knife goes on the left and the fork on the right, or if the knife is on the right and the fork on the left. That is byte endianness in a 16-bit encoding. But when I come to put the plate down (lets forget about side-plates) I don't think *there's only one order to place the plate*, it simply doesn't have an order because it's on its own

Comment: Depending on the application, you might want to retain a BOM at the beginning of the output file. As noted above, it has no purpose for byte order determination, but it is coincidentally also occasionally useful because it unambiguously identifies the encoding as UTF-8. Where everything is UTF-8 by default, this is simply redundant; but I hear some Windows victims kind of like it this way.

Comment: @tripleee: In that situations I would recommend stripping the BOM on input and adding it again on output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UTF-8 is a byte-based encoding, so endianness is irrelevant and an initial byte order mark (BOM) is unnecessary and generally discouraged in UTF-8 data. But its validity and function is dependent on the prevailing application, so Perl cannot simply strip it from the data without question

The Unicode BOM character `U+FEFF` shares an encoding with the *ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE* character, so if layout is the only issue it should not cause a problem if is left in, even if multiple sources are concatenated so that it appears in the middle of a data stream

In most file applications UTF-8 data sources are treated transparently, so that a file containing only 7-bit ASCII data is identical to the UTF-8 encoding of the same data. Such data *must not* contain a BOM, because it would interfere with the transparency. For instance the *shebang* `#!` line at the start of a UTF-8-encoded shell command file must not be preceded by a byte order mark as the shell would simply fail to recognise it

You can strip the BOM character from the beginning of *decoded* Unicode data, whatever the source, with

```
s/\A\N{BOM}//
```

Of course, the character can be removed *throughout* a string by using a global substitution with the `\A` anchor removed, or more tidily with

```
tr/\N{BOM}//d
```

---

### Update

Character streams are read as a sequence of *bytes*, and in 16-bit or 32-bit encodings you need to know whether it is the least-significant (little-endian) or most-significant (big-endian) byte that appears first so that you know how to assemble those bytes into a multi-byte character

The BOM character is *always* `U+FEFF`. Its whole point is that that is unchanging. So if I read the first two bytes from a file and they are `FF` and `FE` in that order, then I know that the whole file is UTF-16 (or UTF-32) encoded with the least-significant byte followed by the most-significant byte, or little-endian, and I can then correctly interpret the rest of the file

But byte order is meaningless in byte-based encodings. Every character is represented by a sequence of one or more bytes, and the data is identical *regardless of the endianness of its originating system*. The BOM character `U+FEFF` is encoded in UTF-8 as the three hex bytes `EF`, `BB`, `BF` in that order, and that is invariant

#### The `File::BOM` module

In my opinion, [`File::BOM`](http://metacpan.org/module/File::BOM) makes a simple concept unnecessarily complicated

I can see it being useful if you have to handle many different Unicode files with different encodings from platforms with different endianness, but in such circumstances the variations in the character sequence for the record separator at the end of each line of text is likely to be more of a issue

As long as you know the encoding of a file before you open it, you should just open it and read it according to that standard. If the presence of a BOM character in the data is a problem then just use `s///` or `tr///d` to remove it. But bear in mind that the BOM character should be ignored transparently on all Unicode-compliant systems

Comment: What if the files come from different sources, couldn't the character be either U+FEFF or U+FFFE depending on the endianness of the system that wrote the file? Maybe it's best to use File::BOM for this?

Comment: @ChatterOne: I've updated my solution to answer your question. I hope that helps

Comment: `If the presence of a BOM character in the data is a problem then just use s/// or tr///d to remove it.` Not always possible. E.g. when you want to use [`Video::Subtitle::SRT`](https://metacpan.org/release/BKB/Video-Subtitle-SRT-0.02/view/lib/Video/Subtitle/SRT.pm).